# Check mongo status on Meteor?

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to create an alarm system for my application, that will trigger when one of the services (e.g. MongoDB) is not working.

What I'm doing is, once the application is started, I shut down my MongoDB server and try to connect to it, but instead of receiving an error my application just gets stuck into the execution of the method. The server console looks like something is in execution.

My current code (coffeescript) is:

```
checkMongoService: ()->
  mongo = Npm.require 'mongodb'
  assert = Npm.require 'assert'
  url = 'mongodb://....'

  mongo.connect url, (err, db) ->
    assert.equal null, err
    console.log 'Connected correctly to server'
    db.close()
    return
```

I've also been trying by doing a simple

`Meteor.users.find().count();`

or using MongoInternals with

`testConnection = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://...);`

but still same issue, when mongo is not running no error is thrown and the console stops to work. If then I start Mongo again, it will just return the result (in this case the log 'Connected correctly to server')

Something that I've noticed is if I try with `meteor shell` to execute `testConnection = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://...);` I get an error `"Error: failed to connect to [127.0.0.1:27017]"`

**TL;DR**

Do you might have an idea on how I can check if mongo is reachable or do you know if I'm doing something wrong with the code above?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the timeouts to be a bit shorter than the default 30 seconds:

```
mongo.connect(url, {
    connectTimeoutMS: 1000,
    socketTimeoutMS: 1000,
    reconnectTries: 1
}, function(err, db) {...}
```

(Full set of connection params are [here](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/connecting/connection-settings/))

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help, it's still stuck :(

Comment: Well... refined suggestion is to bring down reconnectTries as edited in the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
Meteor.status().status
```

from the docs

> This method returns the status of the connection between the client and the server. The return value is an object with the following fields:
>
> connected (Boolean)
>   True if currently connected to the server. If false, changes and method invocations will be queued up until the connection is reestablished.
>
> status (String)
>   Blockquote
>   Describes the current reconnection status. The possible values are connected (the connection is up and running), connecting (disconnected and trying to open a new connection), failed (permanently failed to connect; e.g., the client and server support different versions of DDP), waiting (failed to connect and waiting to try to reconnect) and offline (user has disconnected the connection).

https://docs.meteor.com/api/connections.html